# Assigned data to out of array allocation but program show output with a buffer overrun has occurred

Tags: c++

I wrote a sample program like below:
  when program execution finish this error occur "A buffer overrun has
  occurred".
  I assigned data to out of array allocation but output show i mentioned in
  code.
  Program compile and run on VS2010

```
void check(int arr[])  
{  
arr[0]=100;  
arr[8]=103;  
arr[10]=102;  
cout<<arr[10]<<endl; // output show 102  
}  
int main()  
{  
int arr[] = {2, 3, 4, 10, 40, 56, 69, 89, 99};  
check(arr);  
arr[10]=102;  
cout<<arr[10]<<endl; // output show 102  
return 0;  
}
```

Comment: `arr[10]=102;` Your array's size is 9. Why are you trying to access `arr[10]`? That my friend is UB.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior (reading/writing out of bounds of allocated memory), the behavior of the code after that point is not worth speculating about.

Comment: Perhaps you should try VS2017 instead? It reports *"warning C4789: buffer 'arr' of size 36 bytes will be overrun; 4 bytes will be written starting at offset 40"* already when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you don't pay for what you don't need. Thus arrays boundaries are not checked neither on compile time nor on runtime.
If you are lucky enough, assigning memory outside the allocated area doesn't cause immediate consequences, and the assigned value is still there to be printed.

Comment: *"If you are lucky enough"* I would change it to  *"If you are unlucky enough"*. Hidden UBs are the worst.